# Does the autodie-pragma have influence on the encoding?

Tags: perl, encoding, autodie

Why do I get after the "autodie" a different output?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(utf-8)';
use open ':std';

open my $fh, '>', 'test.txt' or die $!;
say $fh 'käse';
close $fh;

open my $fh1, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;
while ( my $row = readline( $fh1 ) ) {
    print $row;
}
close $fh1;

use autodie;

open my $fh2, '<', 'test.txt';
while ( my $row = readline( $fh2 ) ) {
    print $row;
}
close $fh2;

# Output:
# käse
# kÃ¤se
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless someone comes in with a better reason, this looks like a bug with `autodie` in relation to the `open` pragma.

Changing the last open to `open my $fh2, '<:utf8', 'test.txt';` fixes the problem on my system.  So that could be a temporary work around.

I just checked RT, and this is a registered bug:

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=54777

Looks like it has to do with each pragma using different ways of overloading the `open` function.

Comment: I just worked up a patch for that bug. https://github.com/pfenwick/autodie/pull/12