# It is correct to switch the default perl's IO to utf-8 while using Plack and Middlewares?

Tags: perl, utf-8, plack

Two starting points:

- In [his answer to *Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129) tchrist pointed out 52 things needed to ensure correct Unicode handling in Perl. The answer shows the boilerplate code with some `use` statements. A similiar question about the use of Unicode is [How to make "use My::defaults" with modern perl & utf8 defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412799/perl-how-to-make-use-mydefaults-with-modern-perl-utf8-defaults)
- The [PSGI spec](http://p3rl.org/PSGI) is by design byte oriented. It is my responsibility to encode/decode everything, so for the Plack apps the correct way is to encode output and decode input, e.g.:

  ```
  use Encode;
  my $app = sub {
      my $output = encode_utf8( myapp() );
      return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' =>'text/plain' ], [ $str ] ];
  };
  ```

Is it correct to use

```
use uni::perl; # or any similar
```

in the PSGI application and/or in my modules?

[`uni::perl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?uni::perl) changes Perl's default IO to UTF-8, thus:

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
binmode(STDIN,   ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT,  ":utf8");
binmode(STDERR,  ":utf8");
```

Will doing so break something in Plack or its middlewares? Or is the only correct way to write apps for Plack explicitely encoding/decoding at open, so without the [`open` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)?

Comment: Does Plack write to STDOUT or read from STDIN? If so, it's almost surely wrong (unless they're also a bug in Plack). I said "almost" because the use of `binmode` in Plack would make it not care. PS - now you know why it's not done by default; it breaks stuff.

Comment: I'm in hope than @miyagawa gurusan will tell more.. :) And I understand why utf8 is not default, but, (IMO) the new CPAN modules should be developed  with "perl -CSDA" or with `env PERL_UNICODE` in mind. And miyagawa sure uses it in japan environment, so, should know the right way.. ;)

Comment: I think the “correct way” you list is broken. `text/plain` need a charset so the other side knows what the bytes represent and how to decode them.

Comment: @Ashley, yes - and thanx. The fragment has another errors too ($str vs $output). But it is not really related to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to set `STDIN`/`STDOUT` to be UTF-8 mode by default on Plack, because you don't know for instance whether they will be binary data transports. E.g. if those filehandles are the FastCGI protocol connector they will be carrying encoded binary structures and not UTF-8 text. They therefore must not have an encoding layer defined, or those binary structures will be mangled or rejected as invalid.

Answer (score -2):

On modern GNU/Linux systems you should completely switch to UTF-8 globally. This means setting

```
LANG="xx_YY.UTF-8"
PERL_UNICODE=SDAL
PERL5OPT=-Mutf8
```

in your `/etc/environment` or `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` or `/etc/default/locale` or whatever your system configuration file is. Because of [RHEL/Centos bug](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6585) I symlinked `/etc/environment` to `sysconfig/i18n`.

Scripts that rely on binary input should set `binmode` on STDIN/OUT/ERR(?) or `use open` pragma or should be called with `-C0` option.

The problem is that some `DBD` drivers are buggy, e.g. [DBD::JDBC](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=49517), and you must set the utf8 flag by hand.

```
use Encode qw/_utf8_on/;
map { _utf8_on $_; } @strings;
```