# The correct way adding my own pragma to old perl sw

Tags: perl

I got an really old perl system (approx 8-10 years old), but a big one (100+ pm files). Now for some reason need "remodernize" it - step-by-step.

One of first thing what i want get done is insert into every module my pragma:

```
use MySw::PerlDefs;
```

what will contain things like in [Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Modern::Perl) and/or as in this question: [How to make "use My::defaults" with modern perl & utf8 defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412799/perl-how-to-make-use-mydefaults-with-modern-perl-utf8-defaults)

QST1: What is the recommended way?

1. adding `use MySw::PerlDefs;` so will get

   ```
   package MySw::SomePackage;
   use MySw::PerlDefs;         #my new "pragma"
   ```
2. or add the PerlDefs enclosed in the BEGIN block after the package declaration? e.g.:

   ```
    package MySw::SomePackage;
    BEGIN {use MySw::PerlDefs;}  #my new "pragma" in the BEGIN block
   ```

Questions:

- What is the preferred method?
- What are the differences and/or drawbacks?

*Ps: I understand than the BEGIN exectuted at compile time, but in the above context - it is not better than the "simple use"?*

Comment: [`use Package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is the same as `BEGIN{ require Package; Package->import() }`

Comment: Is there no hope for installing an upgraded Perl, perhaps with perlbrew?  Some modern features weren't available in older Perl versions (`//=`, for example).  Plus all the nice new bug fixes.

Comment: Trying to just patch your pragmas into an existing application won't go well. That being said: 100+ modules isn't really that big. 1000+ is.

Comment: @duskwuff - as i said, that was the 1st step - not the only step. But it *is* a good practice having own "defaults".

Comment: @DavidO - sure it will run in upgraded perl - defining a common "defaults" for all modules only helps later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the use in a BEGIN block is not going to work; the effect of lexical pragmas will not extend beyond the end of the block.

Compare:

```
$ perl -e'BEGIN{ use Modern::Perl; } $x=42; print "$x\n"'
42
$ perl -e'use Modern::Perl; $x=42; print "$x\n"'
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: OMG YES. That is simple... Hate myself for asking so trivial thing.. ;( thanx. ;)